# Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:spring/spring-persistence-layer.xml] even when the file in the path

Tags: java, spring

SEVERE: Context initialization failed

> org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:spring/spring-persistence-layer.xml]
>   Offending resource: class path resource [spring/spring-beans.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [spring/spring-persistence-layer.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring/spring-persistence-layer.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:246)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:197)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:182)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [spring/spring-persistence-layer.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring/spring-persistence-layer.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:240)
>       ... 28 more
>   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring/spring-persistence-layer.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
>       at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:157)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
>       ... 32 more

Answer (score 0):

From the Exception Stack it is clear that Spring is not able to find the XML File `spring-persistence-layer.xml`. Make sure that the file is there.

Try this:
`classpath*:spring/spring-persistence-layer.xml` instead of `classpath:spring/spring-persistence-layer.xml`

Comment: Thanks! that is solved but now I'm getting a new error now. 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'calculatorController' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/spring-process-layer.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'calculatorDao' threw exception; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character

Comment: If it solved the problem and you are happy then please accept the answer and help us close the question. The error you are facing right now is because `calculatorDAO` is throwing an error at the time of Bean Creation.